# Visual Studio Solution References

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am fairly new to Windows Programming coming from iOS and just getting my ropes together. So my question is more related to the process of how to setup my foundation, not the coding itself.

I want to use the Systems.IO.Ports library. I created the following structure:

[image]

NO in the SerialServiceRepository I want to use System.IO.Ports, but this cannot be found. So a reference seems missing, but the System Reference is set. I get the error, that the namespace name "Ports" doesn't exist in the namespace "System.IO", whereas in the Project "SkyOps" I can access it. I cannot figure out, which reference I am missing, or how to set it up.

[image]

Can you give me some advice on this?

Best
Sebastian

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe one project in .NET and the second is .NET Core? You need to give us more details.

Comment: Ha... that's exactly what happend. Thank you! I didn't pay attention to .NET Core. Appreciate the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post my comment as an answer:

"... maybe one project is .NET and the second is .NET Core? ..."